# Two scenarios of strcmp

Tags: c++, string

I have to write a buggy server that will crash due to off by one error. **My doubt is why the below code gives a segmenation fault**

```
char wbuff[5];
char abuff[5]= "12345";
strcpy(wbuff,abuff);
```

**but below code doesn't**

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
char wbuf[5];
n = read(connfd, buf, BUFSIZE); // read input string from client
strcpy(wbuf,buf); // strlen(buf) is greater than 5
```

Comment: Does the first one even compile? Edit: [nope](http://ideone.com/oYCJbq).

Comment: "12345" needs 6 chars (don't forget the final "null"/terminator, `'\0'`); in the second case, BUFSIZE is...? and if it's larger than 5, and no `'\0'` appears among first 5 bytes, then strcpy will overflow anyway.

Comment: Your posted code itself not correct. it should error out here `char abuff[5]= "12345";` cause it has to be size 6 to hold the `\0` or `null` character.

Comment: `char abuff[5]= "12345";` is legal in C; it stores `"12345"` with no terminating `'\0'` in `abuff`. It's illegal in C++, but perhaps some C++ compilers permit it.

Comment: @Rahul: `char abuff[5] = "12345";` is not actually an error. It's allowed by the standard and will just but the five given characters into the 5 elements of the array. Presumably that's not what he wants, though, so it's surely a logic error.

Comment: @ooga, may be but not all compiler will allow it as correctly stated by Keith.

Comment: @Rahul: Derp! You're right. I was thinking about C.

Answer (score 1):

The first one copies from a non-null-terminated string (abuff) to the other string. So it walks off the end of abuff until it finds a zero byte, which could be quite a ways, and causes a segfault. The other one copies from a properly-terminated string (buf) to the undersized string wbuf, and stops copying after it copies strlen(buf)+1 bytes. So the first is more likely to cause a segfault, but both are errors.

Answer (score 0):

Exceed of array's size is undefined behaviour. Something can happen. If you don't have SIGSEGV now, you can get it later in program run.